# Console window crashes after resize

Tags: c++, winapi, console, console-application

I am trying to make the matrix effect using only the Win32 API and the basic C++ libraries, inspired by the cmatrix command in linux.

So far I have succeeded in making it work for a specified screen width and height. I am still trying to figure out how to setup multithreading to check the quit input.
But my current problem is to make it responsive by remaking the buffer if the console window size changes, and with my current code as soon as I resize the window, the console freezes and stops execution of the program.

Here is the code below, the reset is acted through the sResponseReset function which is checking the Console buffer size change in every loop.
Checking the console buffer size seemed wrong, but I could not find a function to check for the change in Console Window Size in the reference.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <conio.h>

int nScreenWidth = 80;
int nScreenHeight = 80;
int MAX_OFFSET = 30;
int MAX_LENGTH = 10;

using namespace std;

//RETURNS A RANDOM UNICODE CHARACTER
wchar_t randChar() {
    char fChar = rand() % 95 + 32;
    return (wchar_t)fChar;
}

//CREATES A BUFFER WITH FORECOLOR BLACK AND BACKGROUND BLACK
void newBuffer(CHAR_INFO* buffer) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nScreenWidth; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nScreenHeight; j++) {
            buffer[j * nScreenWidth + i].Char.UnicodeChar = randChar();
            buffer[j * nScreenWidth + i].Attributes = 0;
        }
    }
}

//GENERATES A RANDOM OFFSET BASED ON THE MAXIMUM OFFSET
int nOffset(){
    return (-1) * (rand() % MAX_OFFSET);
}

//GENERATES A RANDOM LENGTH BASED ON THE MAXIMUM LENGTH
int nLength() {
    return rand() % MAX_LENGTH;
}

void sResponseReset(HANDLE* handle, CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO* pBufferInfo, CHAR_INFO* buffer) {
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(*handle, pBufferInfo);
    if (nScreenWidth != pBufferInfo->dwSize.X || nScreenHeight != pBufferInfo->dwSize.Y) {
        nScreenWidth = pBufferInfo->dwSize.X;
        nScreenHeight = pBufferInfo->dwSize.Y;
        newBuffer(buffer);
    }
}

int main() {

    //CREATING BUFFER AND HANDLE TO MODIFY  
    HANDLE hHandle = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL);
    SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(hHandle);

    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO sBufferInfo;

    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hHandle, &sBufferInfo);

    nScreenWidth = sBufferInfo.dwSize.X;
    nScreenHeight = sBufferInfo.dwSize.Y;

    CHAR_INFO* sBuffer = new CHAR_INFO[nScreenHeight * nScreenWidth];
    newBuffer(sBuffer);

    //OFFSET AND LENGTH ARRAY AND INITIALIZING IT
    int* arrOffset = new int[nScreenWidth];
    int* arrLength = new int[nScreenWidth];
    for (int i = 0; i < nScreenWidth; i++) {
        arrOffset[i] = nOffset();
        arrLength[i] = nLength();
    }

    //CREATING RECT FOR CONSOLE OUTPUT
    SMALL_RECT sRect = { 0, 0, (SHORT)nScreenWidth, (SHORT)nScreenHeight };

    srand((unsigned int)time(0)); //SETS SEED SO THAT WE DON'T GET SAME RANDOM VALUE

    bool qConsole = false;
    while (!qConsole) {
        sResponseReset(&hHandle, &sBufferInfo, sBuffer);
        //CHECKS IF THE UPPER AND LOWER CELL ARE SAME AND PROPOGATES COLOUR
        for (int i = 0; i < nScreenWidth; i++) {
            for (int j = nScreenHeight - 1; j > 0; j--) {
                if (sBuffer[(j-1) * nScreenWidth + i].Attributes != sBuffer[(j+1) * nScreenWidth + i].Attributes) {
                    sBuffer[(j + 1) * nScreenWidth + i].Attributes = sBuffer[j * nScreenWidth + i].Attributes;
                    sBuffer[j * nScreenWidth + i].Attributes = sBuffer[(j - 1) * nScreenWidth + i].Attributes;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < nScreenWidth; i++) {
            if (arrOffset[i] > 0) {
                if (arrOffset[i] <= arrLength[i]) sBuffer[i].Attributes = FOREGROUND_GREEN;
                else {
                    sBuffer[i].Attributes = 0;
                    sBuffer[i].Char.UnicodeChar = randChar();
                    arrOffset[i] = nOffset();
                    arrLength[i] = nLength();
                }
            }
            arrOffset[i]++;
        }


        //CHANGE OUTPUT BUFFER AND MAKING IT 1 FRAME PER SECOND
        WriteConsoleOutput(hHandle, sBuffer, { (SHORT)nScreenWidth, (SHORT)nScreenHeight }, { 0,0 }, &sRect);
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(500));
    }

    (void)getchar();


    //CLOSING AND DELETING HANDLE AND ALLOCATED MEMORY
    CloseHandle(hHandle);
    delete[] sBuffer;
    delete[] arrOffset;
    delete[] arrLength;
    return 0;
}
```

If possible, can someone give me advice on how to make my code more organized, I have just read the raw Win32 console developer's API reference to make this after getting inspired by a command line Tetris game made by a youtuber OneLoneCoder.

EDIT:

The problem as pointed out by @Igor Tandetnik is that the buffer size wasn't being increased. I have tried fixing the function with that in mind, here is the new code, the only changes are to the sResponseReset function and it's implementation in the loop

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <conio.h>

int nScreenWidth = 80;
int nScreenHeight = 80;
int MAX_OFFSET = 30;
int MAX_LENGTH = 10;

using namespace std;

//RETURNS A RANDOM UNICODE CHARACTER
wchar_t randChar() {
    char fChar = rand() % 95 + 32;
    return (wchar_t)fChar;
}

//CREATES A BUFFER WITH FORECOLOR BLACK AND BACKGROUND BLACK
void newBuffer(CHAR_INFO* buffer) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nScreenWidth; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nScreenHeight; j++) {
            buffer[j * nScreenWidth + i].Char.UnicodeChar = randChar();
            buffer[j * nScreenWidth + i].Attributes = 0;
        }
    }
}

//GENERATES A RANDOM OFFSET BASED ON THE MAXIMUM OFFSET
int nOffset(){
    return (-1) * (rand() % MAX_OFFSET);
}

//GENERATES A RANDOM LENGTH BASED ON THE MAXIMUM LENGTH
int nLength() {
    return rand() % MAX_LENGTH;
}

void sResponseReset(HANDLE handle, CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO* pBufferInfo, CHAR_INFO* buffer, SMALL_RECT* pRect) {
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(handle, pBufferInfo);
    if (nScreenWidth != pBufferInfo->dwSize.X || nScreenHeight != pBufferInfo->dwSize.Y) {
        nScreenWidth = pBufferInfo->dwSize.X;
        nScreenHeight = pBufferInfo->dwSize.Y;

        CHAR_INFO* nBuffer = new CHAR_INFO[nScreenWidth * nScreenHeight];
        newBuffer(nBuffer);

        delete[] buffer;
        buffer = nBuffer;

        pRect->Right = (SHORT)nScreenWidth;
        pRect->Bottom = (SHORT)nScreenHeight;
    }
}

int main() {

    //CREATING BUFFER AND HANDLE TO MODIFY  
    HANDLE hHandle = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL);
    SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(hHandle);

    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO sBufferInfo;

    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hHandle, &sBufferInfo);

    nScreenWidth = sBufferInfo.dwSize.X;
    nScreenHeight = sBufferInfo.dwSize.Y;

    CHAR_INFO* sBuffer = new CHAR_INFO[nScreenHeight * nScreenWidth];
    newBuffer(sBuffer);

    //OFFSET AND LENGTH ARRAY AND INITIALIZING IT
    int* arrOffset = new int[nScreenWidth];
    int* arrLength = new int[nScreenWidth];
    for (int i = 0; i < nScreenWidth; i++) {
        arrOffset[i] = nOffset();
        arrLength[i] = nLength();
    }

    //CREATING RECT FOR CONSOLE OUTPUT
    SMALL_RECT sRect = { 0, 0, (SHORT)nScreenWidth, (SHORT)nScreenHeight };

    srand((unsigned int)time(0)); //SETS SEED SO THAT WE DON'T GET SAME RANDOM VALUE

    bool qConsole = false;
    while (!qConsole) {
        sResponseReset(hHandle, &sBufferInfo, sBuffer, &sRect);

        //CHECKS IF THE UPPER AND LOWER CELL ARE SAME AND PROPOGATES COLOUR
        for (int i = 0; i < nScreenWidth; i++) {
            for (int j = nScreenHeight - 1; j > 0; j--) {
                if (sBuffer[(j-1) * nScreenWidth + i].Attributes != sBuffer[(j+1) * nScreenWidth + i].Attributes) {
                    sBuffer[(j + 1) * nScreenWidth + i].Attributes = sBuffer[j * nScreenWidth + i].Attributes;
                    sBuffer[j * nScreenWidth + i].Attributes = sBuffer[(j - 1) * nScreenWidth + i].Attributes;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < nScreenWidth; i++) {
            if (arrOffset[i] > 0) {
                if (arrOffset[i] <= arrLength[i]) sBuffer[i].Attributes = FOREGROUND_GREEN;
                else {
                    sBuffer[i].Attributes = 0;
                    sBuffer[i].Char.UnicodeChar = randChar();
                    arrOffset[i] = nOffset();
                    arrLength[i] = nLength();
                }
            }
            arrOffset[i]++;
        }


        //CHANGE OUTPUT BUFFER AND MAKING IT 0.5 FRAME PER SECOND
        WriteConsoleOutput(hHandle, sBuffer, { (SHORT)nScreenWidth, (SHORT)nScreenHeight }, { 0,0 }, &sRect);
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(500));
    }

    (void)getchar();


    //CLOSING AND DELETING HANDLE AND ALLOCATED MEMORY
    CloseHandle(hHandle);
    delete[] sBuffer;
    delete[] arrOffset;
    delete[] arrLength;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice @JesperJuhl , I have completed C++ but all I have are concepts and not much of project writing experience, if possible can you recommend me some resources I can refer to get better ?

Comment: You only allocate memory for `sBuffer` once, with whatever width and height the console has at the start of the program. When the console resizes, `newBuffer` just writes through `sBuffer` pointer using the new width and height - but the buffer didn't magically grow larger.

Comment: You can detect console resize with [`ReadConsoleInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput), in particular `WINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_EVENT`

Comment: Yes, I forgot to increase the buffer, I tried to fix it, this time I tried allocating a new pointer and the deleting the old one and replacing the value of the new one to the buffer pointer variable, but it is giving me a heap correction error, give me a minute, I am making changes to the question.